# Why does Get-EC2PasswordData return "The parameter is incorrect."?

Tags: powershell, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-powershell

I'm using powershell to call Get-EC2PasswordData like so:

```
$instances = (Get-EC2Instance -Filter @($envFilter, $stateFilter)).Instances

$instances | Foreach-object {
    $instID = $_.InstanceId
    Write-Host Getting password to $instID...
    $password = Get-EC2PasswordData -InstanceId $instID -PemFile "c:\my.pem" -Decrypt
    Write-Host Username/Password for $_.PrivateIpAddress is Administrator/$password

}
```

And I get the following:

```
Getting password to i-3e961280 ...
Get-EC2PasswordData : Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: s
At C:\temp\CIS-aws-volumes\copyToMachine.ps1:12 char:17
+     $password = Get-EC2PasswordData -InstanceId $instID -PemFile "c:\docs\ssh\ci ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Amazon.PowerShe...swordDataCmdlet:GetEC2PasswordDataCmdlet) [Get-EC2
   PasswordData], ArgumentNullException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException,Amazon.PowerShell.Cmdlets.EC2.GetEC2PasswordDataCmdlet

Username/Password for 10.185.30.124 is Administrator/
```

What does "Get-EC2PasswordData : Value cannot be null." mean?  I'm not passing in any null values.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turns out the answer is because the password isn't available yet.  You just need to wait for a while for the machine to come up.  You'll find that you also can't get the Windows admin password in the console yet either (although ti gives a much more intuitive message).

If you've waited a long time, it's probably because your Ec2ConfigService isn't configured on the machine to reset the password.  You might need to change "C:\Program Files\Amazon\Ec2ConfigService\Settings\config.xml".  In there you'll find a piece near the top like this:

```
<Plugin>
  <Name>Ec2SetPassword</Name>
  <State>Disabled</State>
</Plugin>
```

Change the "Disabled" to "Enabled":

```
<Plugin>
  <Name>Ec2SetPassword</Name>
  <State>Enabled</State>
</Plugin>
```

I wanted to post this to the internet somewhere so the next guy who Googles "Get-EC2PasswordData : Value cannot be null" might find something useful.

Comment: What do we consider "taking a while"? My server has been up for 10+ minutes and I can RDP into it. I need to retrieve the admin password so I can rename the computer, but I getting the exact error mentioned.

Comment: It depends on how many services are starting up on the machine.  Are you running a database or something heavy on startup?  If not, 10 minutes seems like a lot for a blank windows machine.